# not able to scrape data using selenium while using proxy

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, proxy

I am using selenium to scrape data from m.skybet.com but when I run script browser doesn't open website browser show message "The connection has timed out". Here I'm am using proxy with selenium because this website is restricted in my region.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

def install_firefox_proxy(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT):
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)

    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(PROXY_PORT))

    #fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", PROXY_HOST)
    #fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", int(PROXY_PORT))

   fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp", PROXY_HOST)
   fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp_port", int(PROXY_PORT))

   fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", PROXY_HOST)
   fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", int(PROXY_PORT))
   fp.update_preferences()
   return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

driver = install_firefox_proxy("163.172.27.213", 3128)
driver.get('https://m.skybet.com/football/world-cup-
2018/event/16742642')
sleep(4)

res = driver.execute_script('return 
document.documentElement.outerHTML')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')

bet = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'row_11ssjiv'})

for p in bet:
    try:
        team = b.find('div',{'class':'title_1nskdmh'})
        score = b.find('span',{'class':'priceInner_14t1nf5'})
        print(team,score)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: If it's a free proxy you can bet the proxy is down.

Comment: I don't  understand. Can you explain this..

Comment: A proxy is another computer somewhere on the earth you pass by first, so it forward your query to the target server. If the other computer is down, your connection to the website is down, because a down proxy don't forward anything anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a faster proxy or try to increase your page load timeout like so :

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
```

Your driver will then wait for 60 seconds before returning a timeout.

Comment: @RaviSiswaliya that's really not the same thing

Comment: You can add the line before you perform the `get()`. When you perform a sleep, it will only wait _after_ you have received the timeout.